# How to use dynamically created JavaScript object in a conditional statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm having this little bump in a function, normally if the variable "receivedRDB" is undefined in the DOM, it is dynamically created in a form and if it is defined it takes the value of another variable "receivedR". But "receivedRDB" keeps being created, even when it is already defined in the DOM.

```
var receivedRDB = document.getElementsByName('receivedR')[0];
    if (typeof receivedRDB !== "undefined") {

        receivedR = JSON.parse(receivedRDB.value.split(",").slice(0));

    } else {

        receivedR = [];


    }
    if (typeof receivedRDB !== "undefined") { //never detected
        receivedR.push(toRemoveR);
        receivedRDB.value = JSON.stringify(receivedR).replace(/"\[\\|\\"]|\\"/g, "");
    } else { //problematic part
        event.preventDefault();
        receivedR.push(toRemoveR);
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "hidden";
        input.name = "receivedR";
        input.value = JSON.stringify(receivedR);
        rForm.appendChild(input);
    }
```

Comment: `never detected` - so, it's always `undefined`? stands to reason, none of your code actually "defines" it ... you say `"receivedRDB" keeps being created` ... where? not in that code it doesn't

Comment: This might be relevant too I guess : var receivedRDB = document.getElementsByName('receivedR')[0];

Comment: yeah, where is that line of code in relation to the code in the question?

Comment: and if something is dynamic as you state, then you'll need to show a bit more of your code so we can see how you are doing it wrong

Comment: It is basically a global variable

Comment: yes, and you state something is dynamically created - if that statement is run before the element is created, then `receivedRDB` wont magically be updated, you'll need to set the value of `receivedRDB` once the element exists

Comment: @avarus It's okay saying *"It is basically a global variable "* but people can only go from the source you include in your question. If something is missing you will find people asking where those sections are or assume it could be part of the problem. It's important to include all relevant source code to avoid confusing or misleading others into thinking the problem is elsewhere. Thank you. Simple debug, place a console log before your if statement, this will allow you to see what you are trying to check... - `console.log(receivedRDB);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution based on the fact that getElementsByName is a "live" list

Anywhere in your code you can put

```
var receivedRDB = document.getElementsByName('receivedR');
```

then change your code to

```
if (receivedRDB.length !== 0) {
    receivedR.push(toRemoveR);
    receivedRDB[0].value = JSON.stringify(receivedR).replace(/"\[\\|\\"]|\\"/g, "");
} else {
    event.preventDefault();
    receivedR.push(toRemoveR);
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = "receivedR";
    input.value = JSON.stringify(receivedR);
    rForm.appendChild(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `<script>` tag which uses `receivedRDB` appears earlier than the DOM (in `<head>` for example). If so, there is more than one way to solve.

1. `<script defer>`

   add an attribute `defer` to the `<script>` tag will make the JavaScript code be run after DOM is loaded
2. `window.onload = function(){ /* ... */ }`

   `window.onload` will be called after DOM is loaded.
3. `window.addEventListener('load', function(){ /* ... */ })`

   More compatible one (more than one function can be called individually)

---

If not the problem please include the minimal code to reproduce the problem.